# Unwanted border with CSS polygon when rotating on hover

Tags: css, animation, hover, stylus

I made a T-shirt shaped polygon in CSS and it shows up exactly like it should unless I try to animate it on hover. Once I hover I get a right and bottom border the same color as the background set for the polygon while the animation is happening. After the animation is finished the border disappears again. I have tried everything from changing border size/color and background etc but nothing changes.  This is what I have now (but in Stylus)...

```
 .shirt {
      background: darken(#1e90ff, 40%);
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      margin:  20px auto;
      -webkit-clip-path: polygon(68% 5%, 32% 5%, 0 24%, 9% 44%, 25% 36%, 25% 90%, 75% 90%, 75% 36%, 91% 44%, 100% 24%);
      clip-path: polygon(68% 5%, 32% 5%, 0 24%, 9% 44%, 25% 36%, 25% 90%, 75% 90%, 75% 36%, 91% 44%, 100% 24%);
 }

 .shirt:hover {
   transform: rotate(360deg);
   -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
   -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
   -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 3s ease;
 }
```

Any suggestions? Here is the codepen http://codepen.io/EricSSartorius/pen/BjZyLb?editors=010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To slove this, I tried

```
outline: 1px solid transparent;
```

and it worked :)

Here is the **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/jinukurian7/pen/NxgqJa?editors=010)**

Comment: Ah, didn't think to use outline. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @EpicSartorius I Tried using backface-visibility and kinda stuffs. Didn't worked. tried outline as a last resort and it worked like a charm :)